# Can I Center Chart Elements in BarChart

Tags: charts

I am generating a bar chart in which each count is to be represented by a disk (or something similar). This alone seems straightforward: simply set the option `ChartElements -> Graphics@Disk[]`. But alas, it's not perfect, as shown by the following example:

```
BarChart[#, ChartElements -> Graphics@Disk[], 
   ChartLabels -> {"bin " /@ #}, FrameLabel -> {"Bins", "Counts"}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Larger], PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
   ImageSize -> Large] &@Range[8]
```

[image]

The first column should contain one whole disk. The second column should contain two whole disks, so on and so forth. This can be corrected by setting `ChartElements -> {Graphics@Disk[], {1, 1}}`, which produces

[image]

But notice how each column of disks is now off-center from its frame tick and label. This becomes far more evident as the number of counts increases; for example, when the charted values are squared:

[image]

I tried re-centering the labels under the columns of disks by changing `ChartLabels -> Placed["bin " /@ #, {{0.39, 0}, {1, 1.5}}]`, which produced the following result:

[image]

The labels are now smaller and apparently invisible to `FrameLabel`, which overlaps them! I suppose that may be corrected by wrapping another `Placed` around the horizontal frame label, but all of this fine-tuning could be avoided in the first place if I can just get the disks to remain centered within thier columns.

So, is there a way to do that?

(Wrapping `Placed` around the disks themselves didn't work...)

Thanks!

Comment: In Mathematica 12.1 this works fine (on Windows). Which version are you using?

Comment: @RolfMertig according to `$Version`, I'm using `12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)`

But it works fine for you? Can you demonstrate? Is there a newer (or older) version of 12.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** A more convenient approach is to use `{All, 1}` (or `{Scaled[1], 1}`) to specify the size of chart elements and use `Offset` to specify the radius of disks:

```
BarChart[#, 
   ChartElements -> {Graphics@Disk[{0, 0}, Offset[15]], {All, 1}}, 
   ChartLabels -> {Rotate[#, Pi/2] & /@ "bin " /@ #}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Bins", "Counts"}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Larger], PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
   ImageSize -> Large] & @ Range[8]
```

[image]

Replace `Range[8]` with `Range[16]` and `Offset[15]` with `Offset[7]` to get:

[image]

**Original answer:**

We can post-process the `BarChart` output and modify the `Inset` arguments:

```
ClearAll[centerBars]
centerBars = # /. Graphics[GeometricTransformation[Inset[i_, a__], t_], o___, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, x1_}, yr_}, o2___] :> 
    Graphics[GeometricTransformation[Inset[i, {x1/2, 0}, {Center, Bottom}, {1, 1}], t],
      o, PlotRange -> {{0, x1}, yr}, o2] /. 
    Inset[i_, {x_, 0.}, a_, b_, c_] :> 
      Inset[i, {Ceiling[x], 0.}, {Center, Bottom}, b, c] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
charts = BarChart[(Range@8)^#, 
     ChartElements -> {Graphics[Disk[]], {1, 1}}, 
     ChartLabels -> {"bin " /@ (Range[8]^#)}, 
     FrameLabel -> {"Bins", "Counts"}, 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Larger], PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", ImageSize -> 500] & /@ {1, 2};

Grid[Transpose[{charts, centerBars /@ charts}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing. Though unfortunate that post-processing is necessary at all. Nonetheless, thanks for the fix, and I will credit you in any charts I produce using this!